# Why does mw2 online launch deathmatch games with only 2-3 people?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

It says you need more then that amount of people to start the match, but it instantly starts it without waiting for more players and honestly, I want to play a match with more than 3. I have only had the opportunity to play with a full server ONCE which was the first time I played multiplayer team deathmatch.

Someone please tell me how to join a match with more because it says there are like 500+ people online. Campaign was good and all, but it was pretty short and Special Ops kinda sucks. I don't want my money to be a waste so can someone tell me how to join a bigger server? Should I just buy black ops to do online?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this game is very old, and out of all the people that play, the system needs to find a match with decent connections, in a fairly quick period of time. Every connection needs to have a connection with minimal latency with the server that you are connected to, in order to be matched up for play. For example, players that are in Europe would not have a decent connection with the people in the US.

On top of this, 500 really isn't that many people, from all over the world. When I played, even after 2 years of the game's initial release, I would still have issues connecting at certain periods of the day, when the numbers would fall below 1000 online.

Answer (score -2):

You could try downloading the IW4X client. Most people will be running that too.

The idea is people can host their own dedicated servers, so instead of having to sift through the age-old servers of infinity ward you can just go to the more populated custom lobbies.

Only problem is if you don't like having custom content running. IW4X servers will likely have custom content like weapons from previous CODs.